# How to tell AWS Lambda how to access relative files Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to get some Python code to run on AWS Lambda. This is my file structure. I'm trying to run the `lambda_handler` function in the `aws_lambda_function` module.

[image]

The code in `aws_lambda_function` is:

```
import json
from server.server_code import process_request

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = process_request(event)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(response)
    }
```

I am telling the lambda to look for the code to run here:

[image]

I have found that when I comment out line 2 from aws_lambda_function, I get the following error instead:
[image]

This suggests to me that it's having a hard time with how I'm trying to import the server_code module. I've tried each of the following:

`from .server_code import process_request` (this produces the same error about relative imports beyond top-level packages)

`from server_code import process_request` (this produces the error `Unable to import module 'server.aws_lambda_function': No module named 'server_code'`)

I've read a lot of articles and Stack exchange threads about how to tackle this issue of relative imports in Python, but following their instructions haven't made a difference so far. (Note: I have been clicking the "Deploy" button each time I make a change.)

Any thoughts on how I can make it so that my handler can reference this function from the server_code.py file? It works fine when I run the code locally on my machine.

Comment: This does work for me, maybe post full code on github and then attach link in your post or attach code somewhere and add a zip file link in your post so that people can try running your code.

Comment: I figured out what it was!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it turns out that these AWS messages aren't the most descriptive or helpful for finding where the actual bugs are. It turns out that what I had to do was to go through recursively through every folder in this directory, add an `__init__.py` file to make the folder a package, and then remove all relative imports and replace them with really long, absolute imports starting with the parent package. That did the trick!

Comment: AWS isn't the issue there. That's how Python's package imports work.